# Is there a Deterministic Matrix with Restricted Isometry Property?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, operator-theory, matrix-rank

### The Restricted Isometry Property (Low-Rank Matrices)

Let $\mathcal{A}:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear operator. The constant $\delta_r:=\delta_r(\mathcal{A})$ is defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
\delta_r:=\inf\{\delta>0:(1-\delta)\lVert\mathbf{X}\rVert_F\leq\lVert\mathcal{A}(\mathbf{X})\rVert_F\leq(1+\delta)\lVert\mathbf{X}\rVert_F \text{ for all } \mathbf{X}\in B_r\}
\end{equation}

where $B_r=\{\mathbf{X}\neq\mathbf{0} \text{ , } \text{rank}(\mathbf{X})\leq r\}$ and $r\leq n$.

- An operator $\mathcal{A}$ is said to have the Restricted Isometry
  Property for a given $r\leq n$ if $\delta_r<1$.

### My Question

Is there a deterministic *(Not Random)* linear operator $\mathcal{A}:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$  such that for a some $r\leq n$ and $m<n^2$ we have that $\delta_r <1$?